# Missing RMarkdown templates with poly-R

Tags: ess, r, polymode

I use the `ess`, `polymode`, and `poly-R` packages together to work with RMarkdown files. I have also installed the R packages `rmarkdown` and `tufte` in my R library. While these R packages provide ".Rmd" templates, the RMarkdown menu generated by `poly-R` in Emacs remains empty; I would expect it to list the templates provided by `rmarkdown` and `tufte`. Is there a variable I must customize to fix this?

Comment: I see you've posted an issue with poly-R. I think that's appropriate, as I can't figure out how to get the templates to show up in the menu either.

Comment: See update on github (https://github.com/polymode/poly-R/issues/6). The problem seemed to come from a call to `rmarkdown:::yaml_load_file_utf8`. In recent versions of `rmarkdown` this internal function has been renamed `yaml_load_file` ([rstudio/rmarkdown@8e62228](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/8e62228334c7036a30ee3edb6871565d69e54bfb)). Once the issue is closed on GitHub I will write an answer here.

Comment: The issue has now been fixed in poly-R (https://github.com/polymode/poly-R/commit/c95f50c60742a487daca3d33578df7ca12702383)